# Evaluation of the right hand side expression before assignment to variable in a loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, list

I am having trouble understanding the answer to this question: [Making a list out of an Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26955308/making-a-list-out-of-an-array)

For the following function (creates a list from an array)

```
function arrayToList(array) 
{
  var list = null;
  for (var i = array.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
      list = {value: array[i], rest: list};
  }
  return list;
}
```

My question is: why is the existing list not being overwritten by the new list and instead the new list is replaced into the rest property?

In the comments to the chosen answer, it is explained that:

> Because the whole right hand side expression of the assignment is
>   evaluated/executed before it is actually assigned to the left hand
>   side variable. So while the new object is being constructed, the old
>   one is untouched and so it's value can be used during that
>   construction. just like `var a = 1; a = 1 + a;` a will be 2 after this,
>   its value doesn't change until after the right hand side is evaluated.
>   The list is the same, we're not editing list, we're changing what it
>   is a reference to. I.e. it was a reference to `{value: 3, rest: null}`
>   now it's a reference to a new object `{value: 2, rest: {value: 3, rest:
>   null}}`.

I can't wrap my head around this answer, what does it mean that "while the new object is being constructed, the old one is untouched and so it's value can be used during that".

How is this loop behaving like a recursive instead of continuously rewriting list?

Comment: on each loop cycle you assign a value to the `list` identifier. So the returned `list` is what was assigned in the last loop. But inside the loop you use the `list` once more, on the right from the equal sign. There you use the value of that identifier which happens to be an object from the previous loop cycle, or null on the first loop cycle.

Comment: So your question *why is the existing list not being overwritten by the new list and instead the new list is replaced into the rest property?* is wrong in its premise. The new list is not *replaced into the rest property*. It is exactly the old list, which is placed into that property. And the new list is a new value assigned to the list identifier, which on the next loop cycle becomes the *old list* and is placed into the rest property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why is the existing list not being overwritten by the new list and instead the new list is replaced into the rest property?

this is because of the precedence of the operators and evaluations, [here you can find the precedence and the associativity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence), thus you have to resolve first `{value: array[i], rest: list};`, this means create the object, store the values and then assign it into the `list` variable.

one example of this case would be the following:

```js
//resolve 5*4
//resolve 20+"test"
//resolve c = "20test";
//resolve b = c;
//resolve a = b;
var a = b = c = 5*4+"test";

console.log(a);
console.log(b);
console.log(c);
```

Answer (score 1):

> why is the existing list not being overwritten by the new list and
>   instead the new list is replaced into the rest property?

```
list = {value: array[i], rest: list};
//---------------------------^^^^^^
```

`list` object is overwritten, however, because of the above, the previous value is stored in `rest` before **re-assigning**.

> "while the new object is being constructed, the old one is untouched
>   and so it's value can be used during that".

For understanding purpose, the above line can be interpreted as below

```
var temp = {value: array[i], rest: list};
list = temp;
```

As you can see, first the previous value of list is stored in `rest` of an object and then list is **re-assigned** that object.